# Can i get any unique identity for new opened window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, window, unique

I want to keep separate values for each window and the values should be kept same for the that window although i reload that window.

Comment: I want to identify each window separately by it's id, Thats it.

Comment: Do you mean reloading the *opener*?

Answer (score 1):

[`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open) will return a `windowObjectReference` which you can for use all [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window) operations.

So if you want to open and reload a window you can do it like this:

```
var myWindow = window.open("http://whatever");
myWindow.location.reload(true);
```

You might also want to read the documentation on [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location).

Comment: can you describe how to use this?

Comment: I've added a basic example. Please note that there are some links to documentation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var winArr = { keys:[] , values:[] };

    var newWindowForOpen= 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226191/can-i-get-any-unique-identity-for-new-opened-window-in-javascript';
    var winExist=false;

    for(var i = 0; i < winArr.keys.length; i++){
       if(winArr.keys[i] === newWindowForOpen){
           winExist = true;
        }
    }

   if(!winExist){
    winArr.keys.push(newWindowForOpen);
    var obj={}; // contais information about an open window, your window information 
    winArr.values.push(obj);
    }
```

I hope it works for you.